# How manipulate the DOM according to if statement using EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am sending this to my views:

```
data = {
 page = 0;
 prevPage = page - 1;
 nextpage = page + 1;
}
```

Them acessing like this:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/<%= page.prevPage %>">&lt; Anterior</a>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/<%= page.nextPage %>">Próximo &gt;</a>
```

But i don't want show the prevPage if === 0, so i did:

```
    <% if(page.prevPage === 0) { %>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/<%= page.nextPage %>">Próximo &gt;</a>
    <% } else { %>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/<%= page.prevPage %>">&lt; Anterior</a>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/<%= page.nextPage %>">Próximo &gt;</a>
    <% } %>
```

This is not a clever way, there is anything better that i can do?

Thanks

Comment: Why is it not a clever way, seems fine to me ?

Comment: does not appears to be a good way..

Answer (score 0):

see [Docs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)
clearly states:

> EJS combines data and a template to produce HTML. Here, our example
>   data has a title and a list of supplies.

`EJS` is absolutely used for the purpose of Rendering the html conditionally based on the data provided. So there is nothing like a bad idea in using `if` here, if you are using ejs for generating html according to the data